# Telnet - Connection to host lost - on port 1099 in local machine

Tags: networking, jboss, port, telnet, adempiere

My jBoss server is running on the port 1099. While I am trying to telnet the port from the local machine, getting the "Connection to host lost" message. I was doing

> telnet 192.168.200.150 1099

[image]

Its showing some other port as 8083. What this error message means?

Comment: Do you get the connection-lost message immediately or after some time? Maybe the server expects you to send something?

Comment: I'm getting it immediately

Comment: As for the error message, it simply means the connection was closed.

Comment: I have tried the same in another system and no such error after following the same procedure.

Comment: There is Trend Micro Anti virus on the error prompted machine. Any dependencies on this?

Comment: There is no 'access denied' error shown here; JBoss is not a Telnet server; and there is no reason why this should be expected to work any differently from the way it has here. Unclear what you're attempting, or asking.

Comment: Thanks for your guidance. I am using JBoss server for my adempiere application. So, while I run the jBoss server, and trying to access the same through application, I am getting 'Server Not active' message Hence I checked the communication through the port: that is 1099.

Comment: So how can I find whether the communication through the port is ok or not?

Comment: are you running a firewall?  If so did you explicitly open the ports required?

Comment: yes. Fortigate. But I made open this port. But the firewall came to picture only when we access from outside right? While I am doing it on the local machine I am getting this error!

Comment: So what you have established is (a) that the server *is* active, because you managed not only to connect to it, but also get a response of some kind; and (b) that it isn't a Telnet server, which we already knew. So what is your question? ***Classic*** [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: @ColinRooney A firewall would not have permitted the connection, let alone the response data that appears in the question.

Comment: @EJP, I realise that but, in the adempiere forums, one of the first problems people have when moving beyond a single test machine is related to their firewalls.  I understood Sajeev was having problems connecting to Adempiere and tried telnet to test a single port. I would expect nothing but jibberish back from a telnet connection to 1099 but, as you say, it proves the port is open.. but what about other ports?  If Sajeev is testing the swing client, for example, then the database ports must also be opened... hence my question.

Comment: @ColinRooney He isn't moving beyond a single test machine. He is trying to connect to the localhost. You are asking irrelevant questions and providing irrelevant information.

Comment: See my previous response to EJB. I wasn’t answering the question but attempting to address his problem! While I don't disagree with any of the points in your condescending answer, I doubt it helped solve his real problem. The question was tagged with “Adempiere” - I have helped many people install this erp since we started the project in 2006, and recognized, from his reported actions that Sajeev was having problems getting his erp install working. From experience I know this usually means their client (the UI) cannot connect to the server. But hey, 2 years later I'm sure this really helps.

Answer (score 3):

> My jBoss server is running on the port 1099.

No. Your JBoss server is almost certainly running on port 80 or port 8080. Port 1099 is its port for its implementation of the RMI Registry, not its primary port.

> While I am trying to telnet the port from the local machine

... which is an action that makes no sense whatsoever ...

> getting the "Connection to host lost" message.

... which is because the server closed the connection, because it isn't designed to handle Telnet.

> I was doing

```
telnet 192.168.200.150 1099
```

> It's showing some other port as 8083.

It is apparently sending you an RMI stub for `org.jnp.server.NamingServer`, containing its IP address and port number, which is 8083.

> What this error message means?

It isn't an error message. It is the result of successfully connecting to the IP:port you specified to the Telnet client. 'Connection to host lost' is an error message, and it means that the host closed the connection. As the host isn't a Telnet server, and you're using a Telnet client, it is difficult to see why you're surprised at this, or what you asking, or what you're asking about.